# How to check user and pass then redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is a template that I use for my project:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/custom-login-registration-amp-forgot-password

I want to use that login template with my phpMyAdmin to check username and password.

1. User input their account then click submit button

   [image]
2. After clicking submit button, the icon will change from arrow to animated circle (At this point I want it to check user and password with database phpMyAdmin)

   [image]
3. If their account and password match with the database, it will show "Login success" message, and if they don't match, a "Wrong username or password" message will show.

   [image]
4. If username and password match, wait for 3 seconds and then redirect to another page.

I don't know how to combine my phpMyAdmin with this login form. So if you know how to do so, please tell or suggest how I can finish this project.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
}
/*=== 2. Anchor Link ===*/
a {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}
a:hover {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*=== 3. Text Outside the Box ===*/
.etc-login-form {
  color: #919191;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.etc-login-form p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
/*=== 4. Main Form ===*/
.login-form-1 {
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-login-form {
  position: relative;
}
.login-form-1 .form-control {
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #555555;
  padding: 7px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  height:auto;
}
.login-form-1 .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.login-form-1 .form-control:-moz-placeholder,
.login-form-1 .form-control::-moz-placeholder,
.login-form-1 .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}
.login-form-1 .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #efefef;
  padding-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.login-form-1 .form-group:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.login-group {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #999999;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.login-group-checkbox {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
/*=== 5. Login Button ===*/
.login-form-1 .login-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
  top: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #999999;
  padding: 11px 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  border: 5px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button:hover {
  color: #555555;
  transform: rotate(450deg);
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked {
  color: #555555;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked:hover {
  transform: none;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked.success {
  color: #2ecc71;
}
.login-form-1 .login-button.clicked.error {
  color: #e74c3c;
}
/*=== 6. Form Invalid ===*/
label.form-invalid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -25px;
  padding: 7px 9px;
  background: #777777;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}
label.form-invalid:after {
  top: 100%;
  right: 10px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: #777777;
  border-width: 6px;
}
/*=== 7. Form - Main Message ===*/
.login-form-main-message {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #999999;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 17px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}
.login-form-main-message.show {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 17px;
}
.login-form-main-message.success {
  border-left-color: #2ecc71;
}
.login-form-main-message.error {
  border-left-color: #e74c3c;
}
/*=== 8. Custom Checkbox & Radio ===*/
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
[type="radio"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border: 0px solid #aaa;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  position: absolute;
  color: #555555;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before,
[type="radio"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
  background-color: #878787;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #555555;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label,
[type="radio"]:disabled + label {
  color: #8c8c8c;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted #f6f6f6;
}
/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #f6f6f6 !important;
}
/*=== Customization ===*/
/* radio aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  border-radius: 35px;
}
/* selected mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  top: 0;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2022';
  top: 0;
  left: 3px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
/*=== 9. Misc ===*/
.logo {
  padding: 15px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* hebrew */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v8/APH4jr0uSos5wiut5cpjrkByb1TKJa77egybnpn19yM.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0590-05FF, U+20AA, U+25CC, U+FB1D-FB4F;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v8/APH4jr0uSos5wiut5cpjrv8zf_FOSsgRmwsS7Aa9k2w.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v8/APH4jr0uSos5wiut5cpjrj0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Varela Round Regular'), local('VarelaRound-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/varelaround/v8/APH4jr0uSos5wiut5cpjrugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
}

button:focus {
    outline:none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- All the files that are required -->



<!-- Where all the magic happens -->
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->

  <div class="text-center" style="padding:50px 0">
   <div class="logo">Login to Smartmeter system</div>
   <!-- Main Form -->
   <div class="login-form-1">
    <form id="login-form" class="text-left">
     <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
     <div class="main-login-form">
      <div class="login-group">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lg_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lg_username" name="lg_username" placeholder="Username">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lg_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lg_password" name="lg_password" placeholder="Password">
       </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="login-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
     </div>
     <div class="etc-login-form">
        <center><p>Additional Text can input here</a></p></center>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   <!-- end:Main Form -->
  </div>




<!-- Ajax Script -->

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    "use strict";
 
 // Options for Message
 //----------------------------------------------
  var options = {
   'btn-loading': '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>',
   'btn-success': '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
   'btn-error': '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>',
   'msg-success': 'Login Success! Redirecting...',
   'msg-error': 'Wrong login credentials!',
   'useAJAX': true,
  };

 // Login Form
 //----------------------------------------------
 // Validation
  $("#login-form").validate({
   rules: {
      lg_username: "required",
     lg_password: "required",
    },
   errorClass: "form-invalid"
  });
  
 // Form Submission
  $("#login-form").submit(function() {
   remove_loading($(this));
  
  if(options['useAJAX'] == true)
  {
   // Dummy AJAX request (Replace this with your AJAX code)
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     dummy_submit_form($(this));
  
    // Cancel the normal submission.
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     return false;
  }
  });
 
 // Register Form
 //----------------------------------------------
 // Validation
  $("#register-form").validate({
   rules: {
      reg_username: "required",
     reg_password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5
    },
     reg_password_confirm: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5,
     equalTo: "#register-form [name=reg_password]"
    },
    reg_email: {
       required: true,
     email: true
    },
    reg_agree: "required",
    },
   errorClass: "form-invalid",
   errorPlacement: function( label, element ) {
     if( element.attr( "type" ) === "checkbox" || element.attr( "type" ) === "radio" ) {
      element.parent().append( label ); // this would append the label after all your checkboxes/labels (so the error-label will be the last element in <div class="controls"> )
     }
   else {
      label.insertAfter( element ); // standard behaviour
     }
    }
  });

  // Form Submission
  $("#register-form").submit(function() {
   remove_loading($(this));
  
  if(options['useAJAX'] == true)
  {
   // Dummy AJAX request (Replace this with your AJAX code)
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     dummy_submit_form($(this));
  
    // Cancel the normal submission.
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     return false;
  }
  });

 // Forgot Password Form
 //----------------------------------------------
 // Validation
  $("#forgot-password-form").validate({
   rules: {
      fp_email: "required",
    },
   errorClass: "form-invalid"
  });
  
 // Form Submission
  $("#forgot-password-form").submit(function() {
   remove_loading($(this));
  
  if(options['useAJAX'] == true)
  {
   // Dummy AJAX request (Replace this with your AJAX code)
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     dummy_submit_form($(this));
  
    // Cancel the normal submission.
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     return false;
  }
  });

 // Loading
 //----------------------------------------------
  function remove_loading($form)
  {
   $form.find('[type=submit]').removeClass('error success');
   $form.find('.login-form-main-message').removeClass('show error success').html('');
  }

  function form_loading($form)
  {
    $form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('clicked').html(options['btn-loading']);
  }
  
  function form_success($form)
  {
   $form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('success').html(options['btn-success']);
   $form.find('.login-form-main-message').addClass('show success').html(options['msg-success']);
  }

  function form_failed($form)
  {
   $form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('error').html(options['btn-error']);
   $form.find('.login-form-main-message').addClass('show error').html(options['msg-error']);
  }

 // Dummy Submit Form (Remove this)
 //----------------------------------------------
 // This is just a dummy form submission. You should use your AJAX function or remove this function if you are not using AJAX.
  function dummy_submit_form($form)
  {
   if($form.valid())
   {
    form_loading($form);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     form_success($form);
    }, 2000);
   }
  }
 
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "consumption";
$tbname = "user";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn -> connect_error){
    die ("connection failed: " . $conn -> connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your html to this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<!-- All the files that are required -->



<!-- Where all the magic happens -->
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->

  <div class="text-center" style="padding:50px 0">
   <div class="logo">Login to Smartmeter system</div>
   <!-- Main Form -->
   <div class="login-form-1">
    <form id="login-form" class="text-left">
     <div class="login-form-main-message"></div>
     <div class="main-login-form">
      <div class="login-group">
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lg_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lg_username" name="lg_username" placeholder="Username">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lg_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="lg_password" name="lg_password" placeholder="Password">
       </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="login-button"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
     </div>
     <div class="etc-login-form">
        <center><p>Additional Text can input here</a></p></center>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   <!-- end:Main Form -->
  </div>




<!-- Ajax Script -->

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    "use strict";
 
 // Options for Message
 //----------------------------------------------
  var options = {
   'btn-loading': '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>',
   'btn-success': '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>',
   'btn-error': '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>',
   'msg-success': 'Login Success! Redirecting...',
   'msg-error': 'Wrong login credentials!',
   'useAJAX': true,
  };

 // Login Form
 //----------------------------------------------
 // Validation
  $("#login-form").validate({
   rules: {
      lg_username: "required",
     lg_password: "required",
    },
   errorClass: "form-invalid"
  });
  
 // Form Submission
  $("#login-form").submit(function() {
   remove_loading($(this));
  
  if(options['useAJAX'] == true)
  {
   // Dummy AJAX request (Replace this with your AJAX code)
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     dummy_submit_form($(this));
  window.location.href = "mypage.php";
    // Cancel the normal submission.
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     return false;
  }
  });
 
 // Register Form
 //----------------------------------------------
 // Validation
  $("#register-form").validate({
   rules: {
      reg_username: "required",
     reg_password: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5
    },
     reg_password_confirm: {
     required: true,
     minlength: 5,
     equalTo: "#register-form [name=reg_password]"
    },
    reg_email: {
       required: true,
     email: true
    },
    reg_agree: "required",
    },
   errorClass: "form-invalid",
   errorPlacement: function( label, element ) {
     if( element.attr( "type" ) === "checkbox" || element.attr( "type" ) === "radio" ) {
      element.parent().append( label ); // this would append the label after all your checkboxes/labels (so the error-label will be the last element in <div class="controls"> )
     }
   else {
      label.insertAfter( element ); // standard behaviour
     }
    }
  });

  // Form Submission
  $("#register-form").submit(function() {
   remove_loading($(this));
  
  if(options['useAJAX'] == true)
  {
   // Dummy AJAX request (Replace this with your AJAX code)
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     dummy_submit_form($(this));
  
    // Cancel the normal submission.
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     return false;
  }
  });

 // Forgot Password Form
 //----------------------------------------------
 // Validation
  $("#forgot-password-form").validate({
   rules: {
      fp_email: "required",
    },
   errorClass: "form-invalid"
  });
  
 // Form Submission
  $("#forgot-password-form").submit(function() {
   remove_loading($(this));
  
  if(options['useAJAX'] == true)
  {
   // Dummy AJAX request (Replace this with your AJAX code)
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     dummy_submit_form($(this));
  
    // Cancel the normal submission.
    // If you don't want to use AJAX, remove this
     return false;
  }
  });

 // Loading
 //----------------------------------------------
  function remove_loading($form)
  {
   $form.find('[type=submit]').removeClass('error success');
   $form.find('.login-form-main-message').removeClass('show error success').html('');
  }

  function form_loading($form)
  {
    $form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('clicked').html(options['btn-loading']);
  }
  
  function form_success($form)
  {
   $form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('success').html(options['btn-success']);
   $form.find('.login-form-main-message').addClass('show success').html(options['msg-success']);
  }

  function form_failed($form)
  {
   $form.find('[type=submit]').addClass('error').html(options['btn-error']);
   $form.find('.login-form-main-message').addClass('show error').html(options['msg-error']);
  }

 // Dummy Submit Form (Remove this)
 //----------------------------------------------
 // This is just a dummy form submission. You should use your AJAX function or remove this function if you are not using AJAX.
  function dummy_submit_form($form)
  {
   if($form.valid())
   {
    form_loading($form);
    
    setTimeout(function() {
     form_success($form);
    }, 2000);
   }
  }
 
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```